# Hibernate JPQL is returning multiple results for a count(*) query

Tags: java, hibernate, count, hql, jpql

I have the below code in my Dao:

```
String query = SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM CustomerData ;

Query query = session.createQuery(query);
List test = query.list();

it returns a list with a size of 2. It contains the following value [1,0]
```

How come it's returning 2 rows when it's not possible, as I have used COUNT(*) in the select clause, which will always return a single value?

Is Hibernate doing something here?

Comment: What is this, Java 4? It even did not have generics...

Comment: you miss the `group by` statement!!

Comment: groupBy is not mandatory

Comment: @jubinPatel: The question seems more about **why** not how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue may be caused by entity inheritance. Most likely that the `CustomerData` is the base class of other subclasses.

So, you should select from the actual subclass.

Comment: In that case it throws the exception org.hibernate.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result:

Comment: Try replacing (*) with the entity alias (e.g. cd). I updated my response.

Comment: Please post the entity too. I am curious about some EAGER ToMany associations.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect, at the end of your query just add this

```
return ((Integer)test.get(0)).intValue();
```

OR

```
Integer result = ((Integer) test.get(0)).intValue();
```

[Reference link](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/19639-dao-count-for-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late, but I'll reply anyway.

In my case, I got 3 rows while I use 'select count(a) from TaskAttachment',

just because I have another 2 domain object called TaskPostAttachment and

TaskDiscussionAttachment, and then these 2 domain object all extend my

TaskAttachment for some reason,

so I create another domain object called RootAttachment,

and then these 3 TaskAttachment object all extend the RootAttachment,

then the problem will be resolved.

sorry for my bad English.